# Why can I use await keyword inside a for...of loop

Tags: javascript, async-await

EDIT: Please read carefully. This *does* work. I'm trying to understand exactly why.

EDIT 2: I know that async makes things asynchronous. Why wouldn't this work for a for...in loop though?

I'm using Node v10.13.0.

For some time now I have been using for...of loops in Javascript to perform async tasks inside a loop structure. I have no doubt that it's working as expected.

I just ran across a situation where I have to explain *why* this is working, and realized that I actually have no idea. Here's a convoluted example just to help visualize what I mean:

```
async function myFunc(array) {
    for (var item of array) {
        await asyncRequest();
    }
}
```

In this function, it doesn't really matter what `array` and `asyncRequest` are, the point is that for each item in the array, program execution performs each `asyncRequest` in a seemingly-sequential way before moving past the loop.

I looked at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of, where I found that the for...of loop iterates over iterable objects. Well, an array is definitely iterable but that fact seems unrelated.

Any insight into this behavior?

Comment: That's what `async` and `await` were designed to do; that behavior is the *whole point*, in other words.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're confused by. Why don't you expect this to work?

Comment: Why *wouldn't* it work?

Comment: Have you read the documentation available on the [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) keyword? That might be a good place to start.

Comment: I know that it works. I just don't know why. Why wouldn't for...in work then? Why just for...of?

Comment: if you inserted a promise in there and used generators or wrapped it in a callback function, or whatever other tool or method you used to simulate the same execution flow, it would work as expected.

Comment: `for ... in` would also work, as would a plain old `for` loop, or a `while` loop, etc.

Comment: [this](https://dev.to/lydiahallie/javascript-visualized-promises-async-await-5gke) may help to understand better and to explain

Comment: I guess I'm just unclear on what the confusion is--why do you think `for...in` wouldn't work?

Comment: you can also take a look at the code generated by `regenerator-runtime` to see what the flow for async await looks like.  it's async await generated for platforms that don't support it.

Comment: `for...in` works fine: `(async function(){ for (var x in Array(10).fill(1)) console.log(await new Promise(res=>res(x))) })()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `async` and `await` mechanism is implemented by combining Promises with generator functions. Every `await` inside an `async` function is like a `yield` in a generator. The transformation of the code is handled when the code is parsed, so you don't have to mess with all that yourself.

What that means is that inside an `async` function, `await` can appear *anywhere*: as you know, inside `for ... of` loops, but also inside `for ... in` loops, plain old `for` loops, `while` loops, whatever. If you read up on generator functions, you'll see that in a sense that is exactly parallel, `yield` can appear anywhere. So `for ... of` loops are in no way special, and (as you suspect) their behavior and semantics have nothing to do with what `await` means inside the body of such a loop.

Comment: Thank you - this gives me direction towards what I should be studying next. I appreciate it!